# Apache respond all ports

Tags: apache, port

How can I set my Apache configuration to listen (and respond) all ports? I want to build something like port tester.

I know that I can edit apache2.conf and add following lines but adding 65535 of them is painful.

```
Listen 1
Listen 2
Listen 3
```

Is there any way to listen and respond to all ports?
Please advise

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea, there are lots of protocols that listen on those ports which you will want to keep and you could seriously break things. For example you need access to port 22 to use `ssh`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't within Apache itself but you could make it listen on one port and setup an `iptable` rule (if running *nix) to redirect a range of port to Apache's port.

That would be something like that:

`iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1:65535 -j DNAT --to-destination apache_local_ip:80`